# KOMA-Script and sidenotes : how to format side (margin) caption and its caption label?

Tags: formatting, captions, koma-script, sidenotes

I am using the command `\sidecaption` from the [`sidenotes` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) with a KOMA-Script class. I'd like to format (shape, size, color) the text of the caption and its label.

According to [KOMA documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) (Chap. 3, p. 118 sq.), it should be handled this way:

```
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{<layout>}
```

However, it doesn't work. Any clue how to change it?

---

## MWE

[image]

(The label *Figure 1:* should appear in bold and small caps)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{sidenotes}

    \setkomafont{captionlabel}{\scshape\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \sidecaption[][-2\baselineskip]{This is my caption}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=20em]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `sidenotes` package uses package `caption` to define a caption style `sidecaption`. You can redeclare this style:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <- added
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{sidecaption}{labelfont={sc,bf},justification=raggedright}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \sidecaption[][-2\baselineskip]{This is my caption}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=20em]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or with the KOMA-Script environment `captionbeside`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\scshape\bfseries}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{captionbeside}{%
  \setcapindent*{0pt}%
  \setcaptionalignment{l}% needs KOMA-Script Version 3.25; workaround for older versions: \addtokomafont{caption}{\raggedright}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{captionbeside}{This is my caption}
    [o]% caption on the outer document side
    [\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax]% enlarge the used width
    [0pt]*% align with the inner margin
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=20em]{example-image-a}
\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with option `captions=topbeside` and a raised image:

```
\documentclass[%
  captions=topbeside% change the position of the sidecaption to the top baseline
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\scshape\bfseries}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{captionbeside}{%
  \setcapindent*{0pt}%
  \setcaptionalignment{l}% needs KOMA-Script Version 3.25; workaround for older versions: \addtokomafont{caption}{\raggedright}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{captionbeside}{This is my caption}
    [o]% caption on the outer document side
    [\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax]% enlarge the used width
    [0pt]*% align with the inner margin
  \raisebox
    {\dimexpr-\totalheight+\ht\strutbox\relax}
    {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=20em]{example-image-a}}
\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you: using KOMA-script embedded macros is the solution I will follow. I should have read couple of pages more in the documentation... Thank you aslo for the `\raisebox{\dimexpr-\totalheight+\baselineskip\relax}{<picture>}` trick: I thought it would work directly with `\KOMAoptions{captions=besidetop}` but it's obviously not the case. However, the top of the `F` (in *"Figure"*) is not pixel-vertical-aligned with the top of the picture. "`+baselineskip`" seems a bit to much, but I did not found how to fine-tune it (with relative lengths). Do you know how to?!

Comment: @ebo I have changed my answer. Use `\raisebox{\dimexpr-\totalheight+\ht\strutbox\relax}{<picture>}. The `\raisbox` is needed because the baseline of the picture is at its bottom.

Answer (score 7):

KOMA-Script has its own `captionbeside` environment (see manual page 121).  With that `\addkomafont` changed the font for the caption as you wish.

Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{sidenotes}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\scshape\bfseries}


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{captionbeside}{This is my caption}%
   [r]
  \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

If you want to use `\sidecaption` you have to use package `caption` to influence the formating of the caption because package `sidenotes` calls `caption` internally ...

Answer (score 2):

To complete [esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318175/64454)'s great answer, I define below two environments `margincaptionbottom` and `margincaptiontop` that wrap up all settings together.

These environments create a *inner ragged* caption in the *outer margin* of the document. The caption is flushed bottom or top, respectively.
Note that the environment work for both one-sided and two-sided documents.

[image]

---

**Syntax**

```
\begin{margincaptionbottom}[Optional different caption for the LoT]{Caption to be displayed}
    <your picture here>
\end{margincaptionbottom}
```

(idem for `margincaptiontop`)

---

**Environment definition to put in preamble**

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\if@twoside%
   \newcommand{\raggedinner}{\ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}}
\else%
   \newcommand{\raggedinner}{\raggedright}
\fi%
\makeatother

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{captionbeside}{\setcapindent*{0pt}\addtokomafont{caption}{\raggedinner}}
\KOMAoptions{captions=outerbeside}

\NewEnviron{margincaptionbottom}[2][]{%
    \KOMAoptions{captions=bottombeside}
    \begin{captionbeside}%
        [#1]
        {#2}%
        [o]%
        [\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax]%
        [0pt]*%
        \BODY
    \end{captionbeside}%
}

\NewEnviron{margincaptiontop}[2][]{%
    \KOMAoptions{captions=topbeside}
    \begin{captionbeside}%
        [#1]
        {#2}%
        [o]%
        [\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax]%
        [0pt]*%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\totalheight\relax}{\BODY}%
    \end{captionbeside}%
}
```

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[two side]{scrartcl}
    %standard packages
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    %Own definition of caption style
    \setkomafont{captionlabel}{\scshape\sffamily\small}
    \setkomafont{caption}{\normalfont\small}
    \renewcommand*{\captionformat}{\quad}

%%%% To be copied to define environments 'margincaptionbottom' and 'margincaptiontop'
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{environ}

    \makeatletter
    \if@twoside%
       \newcommand{\raggedinner}{\ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}}
    \else%
       \newcommand{\raggedinner}{\raggedright}
    \fi%
    \makeatother

    \BeforeBeginEnvironment{captionbeside}{\setcapindent*{0pt}\addtokomafont{caption}{\raggedinner}}
    \KOMAoptions{captions=outerbeside}

    \NewEnviron{margincaptionbottom}[2][]{%
        \KOMAoptions{captions=bottombeside}
        \begin{captionbeside}%
            [#1]
            {#2}%
            [o]%
            [\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax]%
            [0pt]*%
            \BODY
        \end{captionbeside}%
    }

    \NewEnviron{margincaptiontop}[2][]{%
        \KOMAoptions{captions=topbeside}
        \begin{captionbeside}%
            [#1]
            {#2}%
            [o]%
            [\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax]%
            [0pt]*%
            \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\totalheight\relax}{\BODY}%
        \end{captionbeside}%
    }
%%%% end of definition
\title{MWE for \texttt{margincaptionbottom} and \texttt{margincaptiontop} environments}
\author{ebo}    
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \clearpage

    \section*{Bottom beside left}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \begin{margincaptionbottom}[Bottom left]{This is a bottom caption in the left margin}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=210pt]{example-image-a}
        \end{margincaptionbottom}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[2]
    \clearpage

    \section*{Bottom beside right}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \begin{margincaptionbottom}[Bottom right]{This is a bottom caption in the right margin}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=210pt]{example-image-a}
        \end{margincaptionbottom}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[2]
    \clearpage

    \section*{Top beside left}
        \lipsum[1]
        \begin{figure}[!h]
            \begin{margincaptiontop}[Top left]{This is a top caption in the left margin}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=210pt]{example-image-a}
            \end{margincaptiontop}
        \end{figure}
        \lipsum[2]
        \clearpage  

    \section*{Top beside right}
        \lipsum[1]
        \begin{figure}[!h]
            \begin{margincaptiontop}[Top right]{This is a top caption in the right margin}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=210pt]{example-image-a}
            \end{margincaptiontop}
        \end{figure}
        \lipsum[2]
        \clearpage

    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is the `mcaption` package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top]{mcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries\scshape}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\itshape}
\setcapindent*{0em}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{margincap}
    \caption{This is my caption}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=20em]{example-image-a}
\end{margincap}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The caption in the output overflows the page width it's outside the page even with an image width of 0.7\textwidth

Comment: the OP wanted only "figure 1:" to be affected not the whole caption you want to remove `\setkomafont{caption}{\bfseries}`.

Comment: @SAM: "I'd like to format (shape, size, color) the text of **the caption** and **its label.**". The caption goes over the border of the page because the margin is nod wide enough ... the width of the image is irrelevant here ...

Comment: @SAM & Stefan: indeed, my wording was a bit ambiguous. I had in mind ""I'd like to format (shape, size, color) the text of the caption and *-- independently -- of* its label." Thank you for pointing to a package that explicitly works with KOMA-Script classes. Even if I'll give a try to KOMA-embedded solution (see other answers) in order to have a better control on what happens, this solution appears easier to use out of the box and I'll keep it in mind!