# Caption in the margin with scrbook

Tags: koma-script, marginpar, scrbook, floatrow, sidenotes

I use `scrbook` in a twoside layout.
I want to place the captions of floats in the margin next to the float (figures, tables, listings), aligned with the top of the float.
I know that there is `tufte-book` but I do not want to switch away from `scrbook` at this point. So I try to achieve this with `sidenotes` and `floatrow`. But both of them give me only part of the solution.

**Situation with sidenotes**

With `sidenotes` the captions are placed in the margins on even and odd pages. But they are not aligned with the top of the figure.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
Figure goes here
\end{center}
\sidecaption{The caption of this figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
Figure goes here
\end{center}
\sidecaption{The caption of this other figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

**Situation with floatrow**

With `floatrow` the vertical alignment is as intended. But on odd pages the captions are not placed in the margin.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\floatsetup{facing=yes,margins=hangleft,capposition=beside,capbesideposition={top,outside},floatwidth=\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
Figure goes here
\end{center}
\caption{The caption of this figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
Figure goes here
\end{center}
\caption{The caption of this other figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Note: The styling of the captions is currently different. I know that I have to use the `caption` package to adjust this.

Comment: Probably try with `margins=hangoutside` instead of `margin=hangleft`?

Comment: That fixed the situation for `floatrow`, but is there also a solution to position the `sidecaptions` next to the float?

Comment: For a solution using the `sidenotes` package in combination with a KOMA script class, the following answer might be interesting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318175/134144

Comment: Alternatively you could take a look at the `captionbeside` environment that is available with the KOMA script classes. The `topbeside`might help to top align caption and image.